# Raleway font doesnt show on the mobile view

Tags: css, reactjs, mobile, fonts, styles

I've just deployed my website that I built using react.js, I am using Raleway font for the whole website, but when I opened it with my iphone using safari browser it shows me another font, how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you import your font in your website? You can add those lines in your `index.html` so anyone that doesn't have installed Raleway (including mobiles apps) will be able to display it.

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

If you need specific styles, you can select them and generate your import lines here: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway